# Unmapping view model (ko.mapping.toJSON), the first item exists only

Tags: knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm passing the following C# AjaxViewModel model:

```
namespace Db.ViewModels
{
    public class DbAjaxViewModel
    {
        public DbAjaxViewModel() {
            Products = new List<DbProductViewModel>();
        }

        public List<DbProductViewModel> Products { get; set; }
    }

    public class DbProductViewModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

..with the following code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetProductsAjax() {
    var viewModel = _service.GetAllProductsAjaxViewModel();

    return new JsonResult { Data = viewModel, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

Then I do the ko mapping:

```
function callBack(result) {
    sprAdmin.product.viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(result);
    ko.applyBindings(sprAdmin.product.viewModel, $("adminProductWrap")[0]);
}

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    success: callBack
});
```

and it works great. I have this function to add an empty item to my viewModel:

```
addProduct: function () {
    function product() {
        this.Id = ko.observable("-1");
        this.CategoryId = ko.observable("0");
        this.Name = ko.observable("");
        this.Description = ko.observable("");
        this.Price = ko.observable("0");
    }

    debug.debug("adding new product");
    sprAdmin.product.viewModel.Products.push(new product());

    var debugArray = sprAdmin.product.viewModel.Products(),
        debugData = debugArray[debugArray.length - 1];

    debug.debug("id: " + debugData.Id() + ", name: " + debugData.Name() + ", description: " + debugData.Description() + ", price: " + debugData.Price() + ", categoryId: " + debugData.CategoryId());
}
```

as you can see, debug.debug retrieves the last item of Products() array and shows its contents, and this also works great.

But.

When I add **more than one** item to an empty array and do
    var data = ko.mapping.toJSON(viewModel);
    debug.debug("ajax submit data: " + data);

it shows the contents of unmapped viewModel converted to JSON like this:

```
{"Products":[{"Id":"1","CategoryId":"0","Name":"name","Description":"desc","Price":"0"},{}]}
```

The second (and further if exist) item of Products array is absolutely empty. It works always for the first item only.

Please help.

===

Solution:

First of all it's necessary to declare an observableArray:

```
viewModel: {
    Products: ko.observableArray([])
}
```

and then to map like this:

```
sprAdmin.product.viewModel.Products(ko.mapping.fromJS(result.Products)());
```